# django & Vue.js: Why is my VueJs component not showing in the frontend?

Tags: python, django, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to implement vuejs in a current django project. but the components are not showing up in the frontend.
my app is "homepage", I have a class in models called "Games", and function in views called "games"
So here I have my basic vue component

```
<template>
<div id="">
<table>
    <tr><td>Titre    </td><td>Nom   </td></tr>
 <tr v-for="game in liste">

 <td>{{game.fields.titre}}</td>
 <td>{{game.fields.nom}}</td>
 </tr>

</table>
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default{
    data(){
      return{
         liste: []
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.$http.get("/homepage/games").then( (req) => this.liste = 
  req.data)
    }
}

  </script>

  <style>
  </style>
```

**App.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Exemple from './components/Exemple.vue'

Vue.use(VueResource)
new Vue(Exemple).$mount(".exemple")
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>hello this is challenge 2 tow</h1>
  <div class="exemple">
     <exemple></exemple>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
    <script src="{% static 'public/bundle.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Games

def games(request):
    games = serialize("json", Games.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(games, content_type="application/json")
```

I have vue dev tools installed, it tells me that "Vue.js not detected.
any solution please?!!
thank you in advence

Comment: What does the developer toolbox of your browser say?

Comment: when I click on it,it says 'Vue.js not detected'

Comment: no, not the vue dev tools; what does the chrome console say?

Comment: nothing is written in the console, it's empty!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, I should have given a class name to `<div id="" >`
so here is the correct code:

```
<template>
<div class="example">
<table>
    <tr><td>Titre    </td><td>Nom   </td></tr>
 <tr v-for="game in liste">

 <td>{{game.fields.titre}}</td>
 <td>{{game.fields.nom}}</td>
 </tr>

</table>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
      return{
         liste: []
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.$http.get("/homepage/games").then( (req) => this.liste = 
req.data)
    }
}

</script>

<style>
.example {
color: red;
}
</style>
```